# Problema de acentuação ao fazer o Dump do mysql no C# (latin1 e utf8)

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8, mysqldump, latin1

Fiz um programa em c# que faz dump no mysql, é muito bacana, ele seleciona o banco e faz o dump sozinho,fazendo um arquivo sql no meu computador, e eu só preciso subir o banco depois pra onde eu desejo.
**PORÉM** estou tendo um problema na hora de subir o banco pro local onde eu desejo, `(pelo cmd: mysql -u root -p -hNome_do_local < banco.sql`), ele está dando erros de acentuação. Abrindo o dump feito pelo meu sistema eu descobri que ele tá colocando:

> /*!40101 SET NAMES latin1 */;
>   sendo que era pra ser:
>   /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

tentei resolver colocando isso no meu código:

```
Server=xxxxxxx;Port=xxxxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxxxx;Pwd=xxxx;charset=utf8;"
```

e

```
mb.ImportInfo.DatabaseDefaultCharSet="utf8";
```

mas ele continua fazendo um arquivo com **latin1**

O programa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;


namespace Sistema
{


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        String caminhot = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        try
        {

            StreamReader lerserver = new StreamReader (caminhot + @"\server.log");
            sever.Text = lerserver.ReadToEnd();
            lerserver.Close();

            StreamReader leruser = new StreamReader(caminhot + @"\user.log");
            user.Text = leruser.ReadToEnd();
            leruser.Close();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(caminhot + @"\port.log");
            porta.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();


        }
        catch
        {


        }
        try
        {
            StreamReader lercaminho = new StreamReader(caminhot + @"\caminho.log");
            caminho.Text = lercaminho.ReadToEnd();
            lercaminho.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }


    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String caminhot = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        StreamWriter escrevercaminho = new StreamWriter(caminhot + @"\caminho.log", false);
        escrevercaminho.WriteLine(caminho.Text);
        escrevercaminho.Close();

        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(" Quer fazer o backup desse banco?\n\n" + comboBox1.Text + "\n\n Isso pode levar um tempo",
                 "Banco selecionado!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        switch (dr)
        {
            case DialogResult.Yes:

                string nomesever = (string)sever.Text;
                string nomeuser = (string)user.Text;
                string senha = (string)pass.Text;

                if (!Directory.Exists(caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL"))

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL");

  if (!Directory.Exists(caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_ZIP"))

      Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_ZIP");



  var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

  string data = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
  {


      string file = caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL\" + comboBox1.Text + data + ".sql";//cria sql

      using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection())
      {

          cn.ConnectionString = ("server=" + nomesever + "; Port="+porta.Text+" ; pwd=" + senha + ";database=" + comboBox1.Text + "; uid=" + nomeuser + "; SslMode=none;charset=utf8;convertzerodatetime=true;");
          byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ASCII to UTF8");
          byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8, utf8Bytes);
          string uf8converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(isoBytes);
          using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
          {
              using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
              {
                  string fazendo = "fazendo backup";

                  MessageBox.Show(fazendo);
                  processo.Visible = true;
                  processo.Value = 10;
                  cmd.Connection = cn;
                  processo.Value = 20;
                  cn.Open();
                  processo.Value = 50;
                  processolab.Visible = true;
                  mb.ImportInfo.DatabaseDefaultCharSet ="utf8";
                  processo.Value = 65;
                  mb.ExportToFile(file);
                  processo.Value = 80;
                  cn.Close();
                  processo.Value = 90;

                  string startPath = caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL";
                  string zipPath = caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_ZIP\" + comboBox1.Text + data + ".zip";

                  ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
                  processo.Value = 100;
                  processolab.Visible = false;

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }

                MessageBox.Show("backup feito");
                //if (File.Exists(caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL\" + comboBox1.Text + data + ".sql"))//exclue sql
                //    File.Delete(caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL\" + comboBox1.Text + data + ".sql");
                break;
            case DialogResult.No:
                break;
        }


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nomesever = (string)sever.Text;
        string nomeuser = (string)user.Text;
        string senha = (string)pass.Text;




        try
        {

            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection();
            cn.ConnectionString = ("server=" + nomesever + "; Port=" + porta.Text + " ; pwd=" + senha + "; uid=" + nomeuser + "; SslMode=none;charset=utf8;convertzerodatetime=true;");
            cn.Open();
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
            com.Connection = cn;
            com.CommandText = "Show databases";
            MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Database";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            cn.Close();



            MessageBox.Show("conectado, Selecione o banco");

            String caminhot = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            StreamWriter escreverserver = new StreamWriter(caminhot + @"\server.log", false);
            escreverserver.WriteLine(sever.Text);
            escreverserver.Close();

            StreamWriter escreveruser = new StreamWriter(caminhot + @"\user.log", false);
            escreveruser.WriteLine(user.Text);
            escreveruser.Close();

            StreamWriter escreverporta = new StreamWriter(caminhot + @"\port.log", false);
            escreverporta.WriteLine(porta.Text);
            escreverporta.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não conectado! \n verifique se os dados estão corretos.");
        }
    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sever.Text = "";
        user.Text = "";
        pass.Text = "";
        porta.Text = "";
        comboBox1.Text = "";
        caminho.Text = "";
        BT_Backup.Visible = false;


    }

    private void Busca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog busca = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        busca.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
        busca.Description = "Selecione a pasta desejada para armazear o backup do banco de dados";
        busca.ShowNewFolderButton = false;

        if (busca.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            caminho.Text = busca.SelectedPath;

        }
        BT_Backup.Visible = true;

    }   
}
```

}

Eu sei que tem muita coisa no programa, mas no geral o problema tá no:

```
 string data = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
  {


      string file = caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL\" + comboBox1.Text + data + ".sql";//cria sql

      using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection())
      {

          cn.ConnectionString = ("server=" + nomesever + "; Port="+porta.Text+" ; pwd=" + senha + ";database=" + comboBox1.Text + "; uid=" + nomeuser + "; SslMode=none;charset=utf8;convertzerodatetime=true;");
          byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ASCII to UTF8");
          byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8, utf8Bytes);
          string uf8converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(isoBytes);
          using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
          {
              using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
              {
                  string fazendo = "fazendo backup";

                  MessageBox.Show(fazendo);
                  processo.Visible = true;
                  processo.Value = 10;
                  cmd.Connection = cn;
                  processo.Value = 20;
                  cn.Open();
                  processo.Value = 50;
                  processolab.Visible = true;
                  mb.ImportInfo.DatabaseDefaultCharSet ="utf8";
                  processo.Value = 65;
                  mb.ExportToFile(file);
                  processo.Value = 80;
                  cn.Close();
                  processo.Value = 90;

                  string startPath = caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL";
                  string zipPath = caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_ZIP\" + comboBox1.Text + data + ".zip";

                  ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
                  processo.Value = 100;
                  processolab.Visible = false;

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }

                MessageBox.Show("backup feito");
                //if (File.Exists(caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL\" + comboBox1.Text + data + ".sql"))//exclue sql
                //    File.Delete(caminho.Text + @"\Dumps\Arquivo_SQL\" + comboBox1.Text + data + ".sql");
                break;
            case DialogResult.No:
                break;
        }


    }
```

ou no:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nomesever = (string)sever.Text;
        string nomeuser = (string)user.Text;
        string senha = (string)pass.Text;




        try
        {

            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection();
            cn.ConnectionString = ("server=" + nomesever + "; Port=" + porta.Text + " ; pwd=" + senha + "; uid=" + nomeuser + "; SslMode=none;charset=utf8;convertzerodatetime=true;");
            cn.Open();
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
            com.Connection = cn;
            com.CommandText = "Show databases";
            MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Database";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            cn.Close();



            MessageBox.Show("conectado, Selecione o banco");

            String caminhot = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            StreamWriter escreverserver = new StreamWriter(caminhot + @"\server.log", false);
            escreverserver.WriteLine(sever.Text);
            escreverserver.Close();

            StreamWriter escreveruser = new StreamWriter(caminhot + @"\user.log", false);
            escreveruser.WriteLine(user.Text);
            escreveruser.Close();

            StreamWriter escreverporta = new StreamWriter(caminhot + @"\port.log", false);
            escreverporta.WriteLine(porta.Text);
            escreverporta.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não conectado! \n verifique se os dados estão corretos.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: se tiverem dúvidas em relação ao meu código ou a pergunta em si, me questionem por favor, mas preciso de ajuda nesse problema.

Comment: Coloca o código completo pra gente entender como foi implementado.